# espdiff - What is it and how can I use it?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, manual

Recently, while preparing for an introductory Exam on UNIX, I learnt that the manual is divided into 8 sections. While going through the manual, I found a 'games' section (6).
I saw a program called 'espdiff' and wanted to try it...

Here is a sample run:

`$ espdiff
Please concentrate...
No brainwave activity detected.  Aborting.
$`

I don't understand what this means and suprisingly, the manual didn't help also. Could you explain what this game is about and how to use it?

Comment: [It's more of a joke than a game](https://linux.die.net/man/1/espdiff) -- [here's the source code](https://github.com/caldwell/patchutils/blob/master/espdiff.in).

Comment: Also, take note of an important limitation (from `man espdiff`): *Do not use this program while sleep-walking, or before your first cup of coffee.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

espdiff is one Ubuntu's Easter-eggs since Ubuntu 10.04 which comes with it's man page which doesn't really explain any thing but some comics . 
it's part of the patch-utils package,
just read the man page it's only 56 pages

```
man espdiff
```

Comment: Thank you, this meant a lot for a person who looked at it as a rouge file. Stinks it had to get closed as off topic

Comment: @Joe, it got closed as off-topic because it's, well, *off-topic!* SO is a *programming* Q&A site and this question has nothing at all to do with programming.

Comment: This is fake news, the espdiff man page is only a page long but if you can get into the right mode of operation you can access a special set of instructions that help you to make sense of the espdiff "package management utility". Its not a game, but helps users who want to connect to systems that are a bit too complex for even Linux operating systems to deal with.